# Create a regex in python match all hls url

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex to match all m3u8 URL

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#,?&*//=]*)(.m3u8)\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#,?&//=]*))
```

This regex matched all m3u8 url with domain, for example: https://mydomain.example/hls/playlist.m3u8

But I have some case need to match with url with the hostname as an IP address like, http://192.168.1.199:8001/hls/playlist.m3u8

I find a regex for only IP matching. How can I combine regex to match all kind of hls url even it use hostname or IP

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how exact does it need to be? An exact regular expression for a host is complex enough on its own to write a book about it.

Comment: Ah, I want to find a m3u8 url in a document. The above regex is good with normal url https://mydomain.example/hls/playlist.m3u8. But it can not find a m3u8 url with IP address. I'd tried to add a IP regex but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [urllib.parse.urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) for this.

```py
from urllib import parse

p1 = parse.urlparse('https://mydomain.example/hls/playlist.m3u8')
print(p1.netloc)
print(p1.path)
#mydomain.example
#/hls/playlist.m3u8
p2 = parse.urlparse('http://192.168.1.199:8001/hls/playlist.m3u8')
print(p2.netloc)
print(p2.path)
#192.168.1.199:8001
#/hls/playlist.m3u8
```

The named tuple returned from this function also gives you other information. e.g.

```
print(p1)
#ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='mydomain.example', path='/hls/playlist.m3u8', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: Ah, I want to find a m3u8 url in a document rather than parse an exist URL. My regex is good with normal url https://mydomain.example/hls/playlist.m3u8. But it can not find a m3u8 url with IP address. I'd tried to add a IP regex but it does not work

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex, instead parse the url and check if it's path contains `m3u8`, much easier to comprehend!

Comment: Because the url is in a html document, I have to find that first then extract it

Comment: You can use a html parser like https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html for that

Comment: In detail, it is in a part of html like this

```
<script>
jwplayer('live').setup({
  sources:[{
      file: "http://157.230.244.154:8080/hls/ch15.m3u8"
  }],
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  autostart: true,
  hlshtml: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give the parser a shot instead of depending on tricky long regexes like above

Comment: The parser is good but if I can parse all html tags, at the end, I have to have a way to find exact url I want

Comment: Yes once you parse all html tags and reach the url, pass your url to the function above and you should be good!

Comment: Did the html parser help you @Jin

Comment: It can't work as I expect and I threw this problem away. Thank you for your kindness help

Comment: Also if you can explain what didn’t work and why, perhaps I can help you further @Jin

Comment: The url as you can see, it's in a <script> tag, even I can reach it out, I can't query exactly the hls url. That's why I want I write a regex pattern to find out it anyway, any in format as long as the document contain the hls url.